# AWS Athena not being up to date when new data is inserted into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have AWS Athena table that I can search my data in S3; when I insert new data into S3, that new data is not searchable until I do
MSCK REPAIR TABLE. Even though the file I updated S3 is in the same format as the previous searchable files.

How can I solve this without writing that command each time new data is inserted because that seems to make the process ineffective?

Comment: Where is the 'new file' being placed? Is it in the top-level of the path where the data is stored, or is it in a sub-directory? If in a sub-directory, is this a _new_ sub-directory or an existing one?

Comment: I managed to solve it using the answer I received from nicor88. The problem was that I was using partitions that needed to be updated from the created key. 

So I retrieved my partitioned values from the S3 event in a Lambda function and then called Athena to alter the table and add partitions from the value I extracted from the created key.

Comment: @marcus if my comment below resolves your issue, could you please mark it as answered?

Comment: @nicor88 Sorry, marked it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see any data till you run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`, because you are working with a partitioned table.

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE.` simply scan your S3 path and add all the new partitions to your table.
Running `MSCK REPAIR` is generally really inefficient.

You have 2 ways to deal with it:

1. option: every time that a new file land to S3, you use S3 notifications with a lambda function that call `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` - where you pick the partition from your S3 path.
2. option: you can consider using a not-partitioned table, but I really don't recommend this. Using partitions helps you to make your query faster if you scan on partitioned fields.