# Do I need to perform Index Maintenance in AWS Glue for Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Do I need to perform maintenance on indexes for Athena that exist in AWS Glue?  This is a general question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I tried MSCK repair table.  Does this also perform maintenance on the index as well?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "indexes" is something that doesn't exist in Athena.

2 concepts that are sort of similar are:

- [partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html)
- [bucketing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-partitioning-and-bucketing.html#ctas-partitioning-and-bucketing-what-is-bucketing)

MSCK repair works only if the table is partitioned, and it guarantees that all the partitions under your table location are discovered.

Also, MSCK is not ideal to run, as it scans all S3 table location. But given the fact that MSCK just adds partitions, if you have another mechanism to add partitions dynamically based on how data lands to S3, you might want to use something else.

You might find a similar answer here [AWS Athena not being up to date when new data is inserted into S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77350700/aws-athena-not-being-up-to-date-when-new-data-is-inserted-into-s3?noredirect=1#comment136446216_77350700)

Comment: you CAN add indexes.  They exist in glue (not in Athena).  You can only build indexes on partitioned columns.  We have already built partitions and indexes, however, we are trying to figure out if we need to re-run them.

Comment: Indexes are "partition indexes", they are just a way to speed up partition retrieval from specific supported engines. Msck repair won't help you to refresh those indexes, as it just handle partitions.